# Filter Posts by Excluding Categories

Tags: posts, sort, list, exclude

I am logged on as admin

I am on the Posts dashboard

I have Posts assigned to multiple Categories and I have posts that are assigned to only one category.

I want to display posts that are assigned to only one category.

if a post is assigned to multiple categories, then it that post should not be displayed.

The result should be posts that are assigned to one category and as I edit them and assign them to more than one category, the Post will not show in the List after I click save.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the [`load-edit.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page)) action to modify how wp-admin lists pages. Add this to your functions.php:

```
<?php

add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'namespace_modify_admin_list' );

function namespace_modify_admin_list() {
    global $typenow;

    if ( 'post' !== $typenow )
        return;

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_modify_admin_list_posts' );
}

function namespace_modify_admin_list_posts( $query ) {
    /**
     * Modify query here to change how posts are listed, using
     * the set method of the query object.
     *
     * Example:
     * $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
     */
}

?>
```

May I ask why would you want to hide posts that have more than one category? Is this for access-control or filtering purposes?

Comment: Absolutely, I have thousands of posts, and I am importing more every day. Each post gets imported into a specific category. After the import I have to search for specific phrases and based upon each phrase, the Post will be assigned to an additional category. I am trying to make it easier to just be presented with those Posts that I have to assign to an additional category.

Comment: I added the code but nothing is changing on my Post page.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... what exactly do you want the site to do? Which part of wp-admin do you want to hide the posts in? Also, what's the code you used for the `load-edit.php` action?